# Авто сообщение при открытии диалога с Вайбер ботом

Tags: бот, viber

Создал бота в Вайбер, все работает, но для того, чтоб юзер увидел меню ему нужно что-то написать, до чего доходят далеко не все.

Собственно вопрос, как сразу показать кнопки, либо хотя бы отправить сообщение с пгяснением пользователю, который просто открыл окно диалога с ботом?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для этого подойдёт событие `conversation_started`. Сначала Вам нужно подписаться на него, а после - обработать.

Исчерпывающая информация в официальной документации:

https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#conversation-started

Comment: это не работает.
else if($input['event'] == "conversation_started")
не срабатывает никогда. В логах после того как я отписался и вошел в чат заново мы видим 
  {"event":"unsubscribed","timestamp":1598039456589,"chat_hostname":"SN-439_","user_id":"AtMmS5tQY4ilgbCoh+bJYQ==","message_token":5477684186287864371}

фишка как раз в том, что чтобы подписаться пользователю нужно написать что то в чат, что нелогично и непонятно.

Comment: У меня работает. Возможно, вы не подписались на это событие? Чтобы viber начал его отправлять, нужно это явно указать здесь: https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#setting-a-webhook

Comment: я опишу весь процесс сначала:

1. я отправляю инвайт друзьям

2. они переходят по кнопке "chat"

3. они видят пустой чат с ботом

4. ничего не происходит

5. они пишут что нибудь

6. тогда я могу отправить им кнопки текст и пр

а должно

на пункте 3 они должны получить либо авто сообщение либо (желательно) мои кнопки

Comment: @Ozim1, Да, процесс понятен. Вы не уточнили, подписались ли вы на событие `conversation_started`? Уточню, что это нужно сделать лишь один раз для первичной настройки бота, а не каждый раз.

Comment: Можете пример показать?

Comment: Делаете post-запрос на url: `https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook` с телом: `{
   "url":"https://my.host.com",
   "event_types":[
      "delivered",
      "seen",
      "failed",
      "subscribed",
      "unsubscribed",
      "conversation_started"
   ],
   "send_name": true,
   "send_photo": true
}` описание тут: https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#setting-a-webhook

Comment: ага я понял. да прописал

Comment: require '../../config.php';
 $jsonData = 
 '{
  "auth_token": "'.$auth_token.'",
  "url": "'.$webhook.'",
  "event_types": ["subscribed", "unsubscribed", "delivered", "message", "seen","conversation_started"]
 }';
 
 $ch = curl_init('https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 $err = curl_error($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 if($err) {echo($err);}
 else {echo($response);}

Comment: это я добавил ,"conversation_started" - ничего не изменилось.